# how to remove the word "chapter" in the title of a docbook chapter

Tags: docbook, docbook-5

I have a docbook document and when I create a PDF I want it to display the chapter title without the word "Chapter" in front of it.
According to [this](http://markmail.org/message/jrmgqqu4b3v3wyov#query:+page:1+mid:h4sinzvdhbdvof2m+state:results) the following should work:

My custom stylesheet: (doc.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  version="1.0">
<xsl:import
  href="/usr/share/xml/docbook/stylesheet/docbook-xsl-ns/fo/docbook.xsl"/>
<xsl:param name="local.l10n.xml" select="document('')"/> 

<l:l18n xmlns:l="http://docbook.sourceforge.net/xmlns/l10n/1.0">
  <l:l10n language="en"> 
    <l:context name="title-numbered"> 
      <l:template name="chapter" text="%n.&#160;%t"/> 
    </l:context>    
  </l:l10n>
</l:l18n>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I use this document: (doc.xml)

```
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0"
     xml:lang="en">
  <title>Doc</title>
  <chapter>
    <title>Introduction</title>
    <section>
      <title>Purpose of the document</title>  
      <para></para>    
    </section>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

and these commands:

```
xsltproc doc.xsl doc.xml > doc.fo
fop -fo doc.fo -pdf fo.pdf
```

the resulting PDF still has "Chapter 1" in front of the chapter named "Introduction".

I tried different context names like "title" but it does not work.
What am I doing wrong or how can I debug this problem?

**Update** 
I found the problem. The line `l:l18n` should read `l:i18n`...

Comment: The solution leads to differences between the the chapter title and the toc entry for the chapter, because the context title-numbered does not seem to match the toc. What is the right context for toc entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a typo in one of the examples I found combined with a font where the i and the l look too similar.

The fix is in this line:

```
<l:l18n xmlns:l="http://docbook.sourceforge.net/xmlns/l10n/1.0">
```

In this line it should read `l:i18n` (with an `i` and not an `l`)